# Connecting playwright with Appium Services JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, playwright, webdriver-io

I am writing playwright script for web-automation , How to parallelly, installing a mobile app in the playwright code continuously and run the automation.

Please suggest a code to solve this issue , because playwight config file should be the main file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.